# Ошибка: local variable 'markup' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot
import config
import random

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    sti = open('welcome.webp', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)

    # keyboard
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Рандомное число")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Как дела?")
    markup.add(item1, item2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     "Добро Пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот созданный чтобы быть подопытным кроликом.".format(
                         message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
                     parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def lalala(message):
    if message.chat.type == "private":
        if message.text == 'Рандомное число':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(random.randint(0, 3)))
        elif message.text == 'Как дела?':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Хорошо", callback_data='good')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Не очень", callback_data='bad')

        markup.add(item1, item2)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отлично, сам(-а) как?", reply_markup=markup),

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не могу ответить:(')


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda cal: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'good':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, ' Вот и отлично')
            call.data == 'bad'
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Жалко тебя:(')

        # remove inline buttons
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Как дела?",
                              reply_markup=None)

        # show alert
        bot.answer_callback_query(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, show_alert=False,
                                  text="ТЕЕЕЕЕЕСТ")

    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: У вас `markup` создается (`markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()`) только при определенном условии, но используете его всегда `markup.add(item1, item2)`. А что за код хауди?

Comment: Вы бы указали место, где у вас эта ошибка возникает, но если индентация сохранена, то вы добавляете в эту переменную кнопки, хотя вы её даже не создали

Comment: @IlyaBertashus, добавляйте @ перед ником, чтобы адресату пришло уведомление :)

Comment: А, извини. Не знал.

Comment: Ничего, но добавляйте @, если несколько участников в комментариях. Кст, я отформатировал код, в следующий раз вы сами это делайте -- так намного приятнее читать его и сразу видно где проблемы. Я вам подсказал решение, доделайте свой код так, чтобы он стал рабочим и оформите, пожалуйста, сами в ответе его ;)

Comment: @gil9red хауди это ютубер

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблема в отсутствии пробелов

а также как сказал @gil9red последняя строка должна быть в `else`

```
def lalala(message):
    if message.chat.type == "private":
        if message.text == 'Рандомное число':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(random.randint(0, 3)))
        elif message.text == 'Как дела?':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Хорошо", callback_data='good')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Не очень", callback_data='bad')

        markup.add(item1, item2)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отлично, сам(-а) как?", reply_markup=markup),

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не могу ответить:(')
```

все что идёт после `markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()` должно было находиться на том же уровне

```
def lalala(message):
    if message.chat.type == "private":
        if message.text == 'Рандомное число':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(random.randint(0, 3)))
        elif message.text == 'Как дела?':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Хорошо", callback_data='good')
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Не очень", callback_data='bad')

            markup.add(item1, item2)

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отлично, сам(-а) как?", reply_markup=markup),
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не могу ответить:(')
```

Comment: Наверное, `bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не могу ответить:(') ` должно было быть в `else:` :)

Comment: @gil9red готово (◕‿◕)